# Show profile pic in popover menu icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I created popover menu in following way:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.shehabic.droppy_samples.MainActivity">
<group android:enabled="true">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemUserProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_profile"
        android:title="User Name"
        >


    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemProfileSetting"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_setting"
        android:title="Settings"
        />
</group>
<group android:enabled="true">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemFAQ"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_faq"
        android:title="FAQ" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemContactUs"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_contact_us"
        android:title="Contact Us" />
</group>


<group android:enabled="true">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemAboutUs"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_about_us"
        android:title="About Us" />

</group>
```

Now, in first item, I want to show an image which has been captured at signup. I converted my Image in base 64 and stored in shared pref. and on main activity I did following:

```
if(SharedPref.getSharedPref().getValue(getApplicationContext(),"name").length() >0){
        user_name =SharedPref.getSharedPref().getValue(getApplicationContext(),"name");
    }

    if(SharedPref.getSharedPref().getValue(getApplicationContext(),"profile_img_encoded").length() > 0){
        String encoded =SharedPref.getSharedPref().getValue(getApplicationContext(),"profile_img_encoded");
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(encoded.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
        user_img = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

    }
```

but it cannot be set as menu icon as the `user_img` is of `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable`. Is there any way I can show my image as menu icon or else any way so i can generate `ListView` style popover menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Menu menu

     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            this.menu = menu;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            imageView.setMinimumHeight(128);
            imageView.setMinimumWidth(128);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(yourDrawable);
            MenuItem item = this.menu.getItem(0);
            item.setActionView(imageView);
            return true;
        }
```

2nd Approch:

```
   @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    // set your desired icon here based on a flag if you like
    settingsItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); 

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

3. if you want popupmenu with icon:

   ```
   btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(btnExpand.getContext(), itemView);
                       popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(newPopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                           @Override
                           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                   case R.id.action_Delete:                                    
                                       return true;
                                   case R.id.action_share:                                  
                                       return true;
                                   default:
                                       return false;
                               }
                           }
                       });
              // here you can inflate your view
                       popup.inflate(R.menu.second_contect);
                       //popup.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
   // write this if you want menu with icons
                       try {
                           Field mFieldPopup=popup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                           mFieldPopup.setAccessible(true);
                           MenuPopupHelper mPopup = (MenuPopupHelper) mFieldPopup.get(popup);
                           mPopup.setForceShowIcon(true);
                       } catch (Exception e) {

                       }
                       popup.show();
                   }
               });
   ```

Comment: Yes but i want to get circular image in menu item which is generated as:           <item
        android:id="@+id/itemUserProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/popup_profile"
        android:title="User Name"
        >


    </item> I do not have seperate control of imageview

Comment: you need to create framelayout for navigation header. you can't set to item

Comment: wait  i m updating my answer.

Comment: @Dab is this for Navigation view or not?

Comment: No this is simple menu that we create in menu folder

Comment: Okaie Is there any way i can set custom popover menu from layout folder xml file?